# std::vector does not release memory in a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory, vector, beginthreadex

If I create a thread with `_beginthreadex`, and in the thread I used `std::vector<WCHAR>` that consumes 200MB of memory - when the thread ends, the memory is not released. Even after `CloseHandle`, the memory is not released.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

unsigned __stdcall   Thread_RestartComputer(void* pComputerName)
{
    std::vector<WCHAR> asdf(100000000);
    _endthreadex(0);
    return 0;
}
int main()
{
    UINT threadID = 0;
    HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &Thread_RestartComputer, 0, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &threadID);
    ResumeThread(hThread);
    WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
}
```

I thought that `std::vector<WCHAR>` released the memory when it went out of scope?

Comment: How do you measure the memory? Are you sure it's not a false positive?

Comment: That's not 200kB, more like 200MB.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/endthread-endthreadex?view=msvc-170 explicitly says that you must not call `CloseHandle` when using `_beginthreadex`.

Comment: Your `_endthreadex` call kills thread before destructor has a chance to run.

Comment: Even if `std::vector` (and its allocator) releases memory, there is no guarantee that the implementation of `operator new()` will release it to the host system.    Using OS specific functions for managing threads (like `_beginthreadex()`) which have no relationship to the implementation of `std::vector` (or any other memory management done by the C++ standard library) is even less likely to release memory.

Comment: I suggest you use [`std::thread`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead.

Comment: Instead of std::vector? Why?

Comment: No, instead of the Windows low-level threading functions. `std::thread t(ThreadFunction, possible, arguments, to, the, thread, function); t.join();`

Comment: @JeffR -- The implementers of the C++ 11 standard compiler you're using for Windows already has worked out the details that you are getting wrong.  The `std::thread`  and relevant functions and classes do everything you are trying to do, only correctly.  Unless there is a compelling reason to do so (like you're using a C++98 compiler), go with the standard threading functions, and leave the hard work of figuring out how to implement `std::thread` to the compiler experts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ doesn't know that calling `_endthreadex` makes the thread go away. So it doesn't call the destructors of local variables like `asdf` before it calls `_endthreadex`.

Solution: Don't do that. `return 0;` ends the thread and calls the destructor.

Comment: But the MS docs say to call `_endthreadex` if you call `_beginthreadex`, or did I misread them?

Comment: @JeffR "You can call _endthread or _endthreadex explicitly to terminate a thread; however, _endthread or _endthreadex is called automatically when the thread returns from the routine passed as a parameter to _beginthread or _beginthreadex"

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in the [documentation for `_endthreadex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/endthread-endthreadex?view=msvc-170), `_endthreadex` causes C++ destructors pending in the thread not to be called.

So just remove the call to `_endthreadex` and you should be fine.

The reasons for this behaviour are explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71575756/11147707).

Comment: The sentence "Terminating a thread with a call to `endthread` or `_endthreadex` helps ensure proper recovery of resources allocated for the thread." is severely misleading, as it rather does the opposite in your case!

Comment: Yes, it is very misleading! Thanks.